# Локализация title в navigation bar в xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, navigationbar

Программа на Swift.

Нужна помощь:
Пытаюсь русифицировать `title` в `navigation bar`:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString("Question # " + String(numberOfQuestion), comment: "title with question number")
```

```
  <trans-unit id="Question # ">
    <source>Question # </source>
    <target>Вопрос № </target>
    <note>title with question number</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Однако надпись остается на английском, как написано в `source`.
Перевод для других строк работает хорошо.

Может быть, дело в `+ String(numberOfQuestion)`?
Пытался так, но с тем же результатом: `"Question # \(numberOfQuestion)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рантайме  `"Question # " + String(numberOfQuestion)`   будет новой строкой, отличающейся от той, которая имеет локализацию. Для начала попробуйте без `+ String(numberOfQuestion).`, добавляйте ее после NSLocalizedString

Могу посоветовать довольно удобную библиотеку для локализации, которую заставили использовать в новом проекте: https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift , но опять же, все зависит от потребностей и не факт, что Вам понадобится.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Действительно, вариант с 
`self.title = NSLocalizedString("Question # ", comment: "title with question number") + String(numberOfQuestion)`
прекрасно локализуется! Библиотеку посмотрю позже - пока не нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
self.title = "textForNivagatorbar".localized()
```